# Paste formula in a range without autofill

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to put a formula into a range of cells without using autofill. I had it working with autofill before but want to change it and can't seem to get it to work. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range cHere is what I have:

```
 With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    Cells(1, .ListColumns.Count - 5).Value = "STUDENT POINTS"
    Range(Cells(3, .ListColumns.Count - 5), Cells(.ListRows.Count + 1, .ListColumns.Count - 5)).FormulaArray = "=IF(SUM(" & Range("E3").Address(False, True) & ":" & Cells(3, intTotalItems + 4).Address(False, True) & ")>0,SUM(" & Range("E3").Address(False, True) & ":" & Cells(3, intTotalItems + 4).Address(False, True) & "),"""")"
    'rngAssignment.Offset(2, intTotalItems + 1).AutoFill Destination:=Range(rngAssignment.Offset(2, intTotalItems + 1), rngAssignment.Offset(2, intTotalItems + 1).End(xlDown))
 End With
```

Note: The fourth line is commented out. I used that line for the previous way.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried checking if you've contructed your range and formula correctly? Try checking the actual range address you are writing your formula to. Same with your actual formula.

Comment: I know that the formula is correct because it worked before I changed the code. But I can double check it. I'm certain the range address is right, too. I pieced it together in the immediate window.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a go at this.  You have an undefined symbol
    `intTotalItems`
If I try to substitute something in for that and also for variable 
    `lColCountMinusFive`
then the code works and the formula array functions.   Admittedly, I did pull your code apart whilst debugging and defined some interim variables...

```
Sub T()

    Dim intTotalItems

    Dim lColCountMinusFive As Long


    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
       lColCountMinusFive = 1 'Meaden .ListColumns.Count - 5
       Cells(1, lColCountMinusFive).Value = "STUDENT POINTS"

       Dim rngToFill As Excel.Range
       Set rngToFill = Range(Cells(3, lColCountMinusFive), Cells(.ListRows.Count + 1, lColCountMinusFive))


       Dim sSum As String
       sSum = Range("E3").Address(False, True) & ":" & Cells(3, intTotalItems + 4).Address(False, True)


       rngToFill.FormulaArray = _
           "=IF(SUM(" & sSum & ")>0,SUM(" & sSum & "),"""")"

    End With

End Sub
```

What was the error message (if one)?

Comment: The error message I get is "Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class."

Comment: I don't understand lcolcountminusfive. That's not a variable. It goes with the With statement. Of course, maybe I don't understand since I'm a novice. :)

Comment: I added `lcolcountminusfive` to reduce duplication, that's all.  You can revert back.  The error message is complaining about Range overwrite.  Formula arrays can be fussy, you need to change every single cell in the array otherwise it will complain.  That is to say, your new formula array must be exactly same dimension; if you want to change dimension you'd need to delete original first and then rewrite onto blank fresh cells.

Comment: I figured out why I couldn't do it. Multi-celled arrays are not allowed in tablesand I'm trying to put it into a table. Haha! Wow! Is there a better way than just autofill?